My question is a duplicate. Can I give the bounty to the person who has answered the duplicate question?
I had a sandwich problem: something's wrong with my database access library and causes problems in my application. So I've asked two questions: one on dba.stackexchange.com and one on StackOverflow.com. On both question I put a bounty.
Someone didn't like this and has migrated the "dba" question to StackOverflow and now this question is set as a duplicate of my original StackOverflow question.
I just received notice that the bounty I had set on the "dba" question (which has become a StackOverflow question) will expire, and I would like to grant that bounty on the answerer of the StackOverflow question.
How can I do that?

You can't, at max you can flag the original on DBA for the moderators there to revoke it.

@ThomA: thanks, I upvoted that request. Just a question: shouldn't that be a general StackExchange question instead of a StackOverflow one?

@ThomA OP's question is a bit of a different case, they created the bounty on another site and then the question was migrated here (their bounty is left on the question stub left on the other site). This case will probably never be implemented.

Ahh, I misunderstood, as the only bounty I could see was on the one on [so]; I can't see deleted/migrated questions on [dba.se] (and thus the bounty on it). I doubt that transfer of reputation from one site to the other would ever be allowed.

@ThomA: This is exactly why I would expect either bountied questions to be blocked from migration, or migrated questions losing their bounty and having the lost reputation being refunded.

"Someone didn't like this and has migrated the "dba" question" This really isn't true. 5 people voted to close your question on [dba.se], and at least 3 would have needed to vote to migrate. People don't vote to migrate questions they "don't like"; they vote to migrate them because the question is likely on-topic on the other site and the audience there are better suited to answer said question...

... It's not about "liking" the question; in fact if it's migrated this normally denotes that the question is a good question, as bad questions shouldn't be migrated.

@Dominique that used to be the case till this feature request was implemented (You couldn't migrate bountied questions).

You can't award a bounty on a duplicate target, there is a feature request to allow that but your case is a bit different and will most likely never be allowed.
When a bountied question is migrated the bounty is left on the original site (You can see your original question on DBA). This is done because otherwise it would allow abuse vectors where people could transfer reputation between sites and / or raise a bounty on a site where they don't have enough reputation to do so.
At best what you can do is raise a mod flag on your question on DBA and ask the moderators there to revoke your bounty.

I would expect either bountied questions to be blocked from migration, or migrated questions losing their bounty and having the lost reputation being refunded.

@Dominique there's a discussion here on what should happen when a bountied question is closed, you can pitch in there if you want.

I suspect that refunding a bounty on a question, after it's closed (migration is a form of closure), could be open to abuse, @Dominique . Also, we're all humans here. [dba.se] is a smaller community, so likely misses fewer posts, but bounties could (previously) be used to avoid closure for very off-topic questions that had missed curation. The bounty is now a (little bit of a) double edged sword; you get the attention from the bounty you want, but that attention could now be swift closure.

If nothing else happens then the OP will get the 200 rep back in a month when the migration stub is deleted.
